# Routing error with multiple models - devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Actually I am using two models for my app that is User and Admin and I followed every steps to be dealt while using devise gem.

And I would like to have multiple sign_up. When User sign_up, must be redirected to User sign_up page and when Admin sign_up, must be redirected to Admin sign_up page in order to make registrations.

When I execute sign_up link under User it gives me routing error which is as below;

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Users::RegistrationsController
```

And When I execute sign_up link under Admin it gives me routing error which is as below;

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Admins::RegistrationsController
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    root "home#index"

    devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'users/sessions',
        registrations: 'users/registrations'
    }   

    get '/aslani' => 'aslani#index', as: :authenticated_user_root

    devise_for :admins, controllers: {
        sessions: 'admins/sessions',
        registrations: 'admins/registrations'
    }


    get '/kola' => 'kola#index', as: :authenticated_admin_root
end
```

aslani/index.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
      I am Aslani.
       <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to 'Log In', new_user_session_path %>
      <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>
```

kola/index.html.erb

```
<% if admin_signed_in? %>
       I am Kola.
      <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to 'Log In', new_admin_session_path %></li>
      <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_admin_registration_path %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def new
        super
    end

    def create 
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options) 
        sign_in(resource_name, resource) 
        yield resource if block_given? 
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
    end

end
```

app/controllers/admins/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def new
        super
    end

    def create 
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options) 
        sign_in(resource_name, resource) 
        yield resource if block_given? 
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
    end

end
```

app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create 
        super
    end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

app/controllers/admins/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Admins::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create 
         super
    end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you have overriden registrations_controller also?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes I do have overridden  registrations_controllers for the User and Admin.

Comment: Routing error issues are solved but I am getting Missing template users/registrations/create and  Missing template admins/registrations/create errors.Just have a look I have updated my post.

Comment: Add super in create action or remove it because you have written nothing .

Comment: Thanks. I added the super.

Comment: Actually I want to create different profiles for the customers, so do I need to create each model for the individual profile with multiple logins. Is this the better way or have some other simple ways of doing it.Hope you understand the matter.

Comment: What you are doing is right, have them separate. If you merge them in single table it will be hard to manage login, signup and other devise actions. But if you want to know how to achieve that take a look here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role

Comment: Can't I achieve the same with pundit?

Comment: Yes, roles and users both are completely different, a user/admin/customer can have many roles which you can manage easily by using pundit.

Comment: I believe pundit should used if you want role based authorization.

Comment: Thank you very much.I got it. How can I login with single login form for multiple users? Do I need to create a custom login form or any other way?

Comment: How you will detect whether the user who wants to login is an admin or customer or simply user. What if customer wants to register as both user and customer. You must have separate login forms for all three types of users and I think devise will add those views per resource type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120298/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per discussion with @Muhammad

He is getting missing template admins/registrations/create error, 
To solve this, either add super or delete create action because he has overridden nothing

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end  

  def create
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```